# Debugging a javascript error that only occurs on the live site

Tags: javascript

Something broke and I get "Object Expected" error on my live site, but I can't figure out where. If I run visual studio at the same time, it breakpoints it and shows the error as being half way along the viewstate, highlighted yellow... which is useless as its just gobbledegook.

How can I debug this? I want to know what javascript its trying to run that is breaking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox and Firebug.

http://getfirebug.com/

Never debug Javascript without it.

Comment: Told me straight away where the problem was.

Comment: If you must use a browser other than Firefox you can try Firebug Lite.
http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ScriptCanary.com](http://ScriptCanary.com) so you can get all the details from live site errors and vastly improve your chances of quickly fixing them.